# How to test if STDIN is terminal in batch?

Tags: batch-file, window, stdin

In shell I can do this:

```
if test -t 0  ; then
  echo stdin is a tty
  exit 0
fi
```

How can I do this in batch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDITED - Thank you to all the testers.

```
@echo off
    timeout 1 2>nul >nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo input redirected
    ) else (
        echo input is console
    )
```

The timeout command tries to directly get access to the console, and this will fail if the batch file is executed as

```
myBatchFile.cmd < input.txt
echo something | myBatchFile.cmd
```

Tested on Windows XP (timeout from W2003 Resource Kit), 7 and 8.1.

Comment: +1 It works here! Tested in Windows 8.1 (I like this...)

Comment: `timeout 0 2>nul >nul` also seems to work and avoids the 1 second delay.

Comment: @rivy, just from memory (4 years later), and maybe I'm wrong, I belive the reason for the `1` was there was some version of the `timeout` executable that didn't allow a `0` as a valid value. But at this moment I'm limited to W10 64b and at least in this version you are right. Thank you