# How to Detect StandardInput from Process (on batch script)

Tags: c#, batch-file, process, redirectstandardoutput

I'm building a control that processes batch scripts. It uses "Redirect[...]" to get the error and output, then passes them into a TextBox.

I would like to be able to allow the user to provide input, when necessary.

The requirements are:

- Any .bat file may be supplied. Ergo, a hard-wired mechanism for checking within the output stream (such as looking for ":" or "?") is not possible.
- If ShellExecute can be used in combination with getting error and output that is fine.

To be clear: my problem is knowing at which point an input is required when the Process has started, prompting a user for it and then supplying it back to the process.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible.

AFAIK there there is no way to know that Process is waiting for input.

You have to this other way, maybe for example putting some echos in batch files that would indicate that the user need to put some input.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize in advance if this is not what you asked.

On a Batch script you may detect if the Standard Input was redirected to a disk file using `timeout` command so, for example, if the input is not redirected, prompt the user; otherwise, just read from the redirected file:

```
timeout 1 >nul 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 (
   rem Input redirected: just read from redirected file
   set /P variable=
) else (
   rem Input is console: prompt the user
   set /P "variable=Enter the variable value: "
)
```

Further details at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726198/how-to-test-if-stdin-is-terminal-in-batch/22728815).