# timeout command not working in batch files

Tags: java, batch-file

I am trying to invoke a batch file through a tomcat application. The batch is executed properly, but the timeout command in the batch does not pause the batch. When a batch is executed directly, the timeout does pause the process as expected.

I am invoking batch as:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("test.bat");

Comment: have you ran **TIMEOUT** with the **/NOBREAK** option. This will rule out if there is some sort of continued interaction effectively pressing a key.

Answer (score 15):

When you call `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` the input and output streams of the started process are redirected. `timeout` being started from this process inherits the same handles.

The problem is that `timeout` [tries to get access to the console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22726198/2861476), something it can not do because of the redirection.

You can test this behaviour running from a console

```dos
<nul timeout /t 10
```

When the input stream is redirected, `timeout` fails.

One workaround could be

```dos
( timeout /t 10 || >nul ping -n 11 localhost ) 2>nul
```

If the `timeout` fails, a `ping` command is executed to force the wait.

Comment: Tested this on Windows 10 and it's working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but maybe it helps someone. You can use a powershell command inside a .bat file and also use Java ProcessBuilder to keep the standard input but discard all outputs.

In the bat file:

```
powershell -noprofile -command "& {[system.threading.thread]::sleep(5000)}"
```

Java:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C", "do.bat");
            processBuilder.inheritIO();
            processBuilder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.DISCARD);
            processBuilder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.DISCARD);
            processBuilder.start();
```

This will silently execute the batch file, including the wait.