# Batch timeout command fails in Windows 2012 R2 Standard in 1st loop iteration

Tags: batch-file, timeout, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to pause for 12 hours with the timeout command in a loop.
I run the following:

```
    echo Wait for 12 hours
    echo off
    for /L %%i in (1,1,12) do (
        timeout /t 3600 
        echo Ran for %%i hrs
    )
    echo on
```

The command seems to get stuck in the command window at:

```
    Waiting for 3329 seconds, press a key to continue ...
```

I looked at this page "[timeout command not working in batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543744/timeout-command-not-working-in-batch-files)", but I'm not using redirection to call this in my .CMD file. I am running it by rt-click, run as administrator.

When I tried to copy the windows' text by highlighting it and pressing `ENTER`, it  acted the same as if I typed `ENTER` stopped that first timeout which was stuck, and started the next timeout. This one seems to be working.

The original one shows that it timed out for 730 seconds, and the next timeout was at 3120 and counting. I think it's 730 seconds because the output is:

```
    Waiting for 730 seconds, press a key to continue ...
    Ran for 1 hrs

    Waiting for 3120 seconds, press a key to continue ...
```

This runs fine on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, but is failing on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard with no service pack.

Comment: Do you need the countdown? If not try it with the output redirected to `nul`, e.g. `(timeout /t 3600 > nul)`.

Comment: I would first suggest changing it to `TIMEOUT /T 3600 /NOBREAK>NUL` but really see no reason why you cannot just use `TIMEOUT /T 43200 /NOBREAK>NUL` without the loop.

Comment: @Compo because he wants an hourly feedback.

Comment: I'm not sure, if "waiting for 12 hours" is the way to go. A scheduled task might be a better choice. Hard to say without knowing your reasons.

Comment: @Compo - (and erykun) Yes, I wanted to see progress quickly without doing division! :-) 
It appears this is working fine now. It failed two times in a row. I don't know why. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: My use of `>NUL` was part of a response to the comment directly above mine, _sorry for not making that clear_. I still recommend using the /NOBREAK option which was my main intent when making my comment.

Comment: do you have "Quick Edit Mode" turned on? if yes, a mouse click into the window will start marking a text (white box), suspending execution until you press a key (or secondary mouse button).

Comment: @Stephan - I always use Quick Edit, but I see your point; ditto to Compo. Once the kinks are worked our I'll switch to that. I wasn't thinking I could use ctrl-C to break with the /NOBREAK option. Thanks