# Executing a batch script on Windows from Java that honors waits

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I have a situation where I have a batch script I need to shell out from Java and call. That is all well and good and easy enough but the issue I am having is that I cannot seem to call it in any way that actually honors any waitfor, timeout, or pause commands commands.

I have this batch file as a test that just writes to a file, waits 10 seconds, and then writes to the file again and exits.

```
@echo off
@echo.>"testFile.txt"
@echo %time% "Script has started" >> "testFile.txt"
timeout /t 10 /nobreak
@echo %time% "Script has ended" >> "testFile.txt"
```

This works exactly as expected when running from command line and I get a file containing two messages 10 seconds apart like this:

```
11:24:52.01 "Script has started" 
11:25:02.11 "Script has ended"
```

When running that exact same script with this java code:

```
final String command = "cmd.exe /c start /b <path to bat file>\run-test.bat";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

I get an output file with the two log lines just ms apart like this:

```
11:32:18.85 "Script has started" 
11:32:18.89 "Script has ended"
```

This is the same behavior for both waitFor and pause commands in all batch files I have tried. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to get it to honor these commands or any insight into why it is not honoring them?

Thanks

Comment: 1st why do you use `start /b` ? 2nd did you try the olf fashioned `ping -n 9 localhost >Nul` for the delay?

Comment: Found the answer to why this was not working here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543744/timeout-command-not-working-in-batch-files

Comment: I had that in the back of my mind; that's why I suggested ping, which I'd use 1st place instead of execution on fail of timeout.

Comment: @LotPings, you'd need `ping -n 11 localhost` to wait for 10 seconds... ;-)

Comment: @aschipfl :-p I knew there was one difference, when I remembered correctly it was to late to change the comment.